Use decorator for repeated overloading
TLDR
I'm trying to make my type checker happy by specifying overloading of my functions. There is a specific signature I have many of, and I'd like to keep things dry.
Example and current code
I have many functions that take, as their first argument, an int or a float, and return the same type. To make sure my editor understands the one-to-one mapping, I add overloading:
from typing import overload

@overload
def add_two(x: int) -> int: ...

@overload
def add_two(x: float) -> float: ...

def add_two(x: int | float) -> int | float:
    return x + 2

This works, great.
Now, I have many such functions, e.g.
def add_two(x: int | float) -> int | float:
    return x + 2

def square(x: int | float) -> int | float:
    return x ** 2

def multiply_by_int_add_int(x: int | float, y: int, z: int) -> int | float:
    return x * y + z

(...)

Adding the overloading in the way it's described, to each of the functions, will add a lot of almost identical code.
Question
Is there a way to write a decorator such, that I can add it to each function definition?
Note that:

The functions have in common, that the type of the first argument determines the type of the return value.

The number and type of the remaining parameters is not pre-determined.


Current attempt
import functools
from typing import Callable, ParamSpec, TypeVar, overload

T = TypeVar("T")
P = ParamSpec("P")


def int2int_and_float2float(fn: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, T]:

    @overload
    def wrapped(x: int, *args, **kwargs) -> int: ...

    @overload
    def wrapped(x: float, *args, **kwargs) -> float: ...

    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def wrapped(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs):
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped

@int2int_and_float2float
def add_two(x: int | float) -> int | float:
    """Add two"""
    return x * 2

This is not working; add_two(3) is not recognised to give an integer:

What am I missing?
(I want to support python >=3.10)

Make the functions generic, rather than using overloading.
T = TypeVar('T', int, float)

def add_two(x: T) -> T:
    return x + 2

def square(x: T) -> T:
    return x ** 2

def multiply_by_int_add_int(x: T, y: int, z: int) -> T:
    return x * y + z


Ah, that's a lot easier than I thought! Many thanks.
This is a different question, but - could I adjust this to specify a different mapping? e.g. float -> str, int -> List? There is a mapping like this that I also use in many functions.

So if the first argument is float, the return value is a str, etc? That would be a case for overloading. There is no provision for type-level functions that would allow you to take a type variable as an argument and return some other type that depends on the "value" of the argument.

@ElRudi in general case, where overloads are not T->T, you could use something like this: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=42933e56a26d6f8b46c3ce2b77605084
